# In R, How do I set plot size when plotting to raw png (byte array)

Tags: r, plot

I was able to save a plot to a variable by following [In R, how to plot into a memory buffer instead of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171523/in-r-how-to-plot-into-a-memory-buffer-instead-of-a-file)

I haven't been able to set the height and width of the resulting image without crashing R and my Java program. (R is called from a Java program using REngine running on Mac OSX Lion).

Before plotting, I have tried both:

```
windows.options(width=2, height=2)
```

and

```
Cairo(width=2, height=2,file='/dev/null')
```

No dice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it is always helpful if you submit a working example.

Second, have you read the `?png`?

Third, if you share your end goal it is easier for us to suggest possible solutions and understand your problem (maybe you can get out of running R in a Java program).

Here is how I would do it, though it does sound as you do not what the png on your hard disk?

```
png("mygraph.png",  width = 480, height = 480, units = "px")
plot(sin, -pi, 2*pi)
dev.off()
```

Let me know if this works for you or try to be more specific in your question.

Best, Eric

Comment: Thanks Eric,
I needed to specify 'png' in the Cairo call, then I can pass in height and width as pixels. I figured this out while thinking about your questions.

Cairo(250, 250, '/dev/null', 'png')

Comment: @ Mick; Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cairo(width=250, height=250, '/dev/null', 'png')
```