# In R, how to plot in SVG format and output to memory buffer instead of file

Tags: r

Is there anyway to plot SVG to memory buffer instead of file?

I'm trying to embed R into my own app, so I can use R to generate svg charts. I would like to avoid generating file and then read svg file to my app.

I found this [In R, how to plot into a memory buffer instead of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171523/in-r-how-to-plot-into-a-memory-buffer-instead-of-a-file), but it's for png format.

It would be great if we can do something similar to svg and save svg content to a string variable

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gridSVG package might be useful:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridSVG)


ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) + geom_point()

SVGlist <- grid.export(name = NULL)
str(SVGlist, 1)
#List of 4
# $ svg     :Classes 'XMLInternalElementNode', 'XMLInternalNode', 'XMLAbstractNode' <externalptr> 
# $ coords  :List of 18
# $ mappings:List of 5
# $ utils   : chr "// Note that this code is documented using JSDoc and guided by the following URLs:\n// http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/w"| _truncated__

SVGlist$svg
#the SVG code
```

However, this still needs to print to the graphics device.

Comment: thanks a lot, @Roland! this is what i need, i'm planning to send the svg code to web browser.

ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) + geom_point()

this statement actually opened a window to display the plot, is there anyway to supress it, but still generate the svg? i want this to work on the server side.

Comment: the new `svglite` package https://github.com/hadley/svglite offers this functionality with `svgstring()`.