# Is there a way to save a grob directly to a rasterGrob?

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, rasterizing, grob

I'm drawing several `ggplot2` objects and placing them on a `grid.arrange` inside a call to a 'pdf' device.  I've found that the PDF performs about a billion times better (generates faster, renders faster) if I rasterize the plots first.  So inside a parallel `dlply` loop, I'm using `ggsave` to write the `ggplot2` as a PNG, then using `readPNG` to read it back in and `rasterGrob` to convert return it to the `dlply`.   The `dlply` puts it into a list of `grobs` which `grid.arrange` then draws to the PDF device.

Some of this seems unwieldy, so in general, is there a better approach?  But what really bugs me is writing the PNGs to disk when all I do with them is read them back in.  Is there a way to save a grob directly to a rasterGrob?

```
plot.list <- dlply( ... {
        ggsave(filename= fname
               ,plot= my.plot
               ,device= "png" 
               ,scale = 1, width= 1.1, height= 2.125, units = "in" 
               ,dpi = dpi)

        # return it as a list of rasters
        rasterGrob(readPNG( source= fname, info= TRUE))
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Doesn't look easy. This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171523/in-r-how-to-plot-into-a-memory-buffer-instead-of-a-file . You would use the Cairo graphics device directly rather than going though `ggsave`

Comment: I sympathise with the question (I've always wanted a way to rasterise a specific plot layer), but if you're rasterising the whole image I'm not sure what you gain by making a pdf as opposed to a png?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the Cairo graphics device as outlined in @Yang 's [In R, how to plot into a memory buffer instead of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171523/in-r-how-to-plot-into-a-memory-buffer-instead-of-a-file#answer-7181495) answer suggested by @MrFlick